# How to Remove a Kubernetes (GKE) Cluster node-pool without down-time

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am using Google Kubernetes Engine.
I have a multiple Kubernetes cluster node-pools.
I want to delete one of them.

Is there a way that I can first migrate all the pods on one node-pool to another node-pool through the same kind of rolling update methods found in other features?

I thought it would do this automatically for me.
But when I deleted the node-pool I got downtime, luckily this was not a production environment.

I would like to know if there is a way to automatically migrate and move all pods from one node-pool to another node-pool and slowly roll the change when a node-pool is removed?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you cordon and drain the nodepool before deleting it, then you can avoid downtime. I use the following script (shamelessly taken from the lazyweb elsewhere and adapted to my needs):

```
oldpool=pool-1
oldnodes=$(k get no --selector='cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool='$oldpool -o json | jq .items[].metadata.name -r | xargs)

kubectl cordon --selector='cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool='$oldpool

for n in $oldnodes; do
  echo "draining $n"
  kubectl drain --delete-local-data --ignore-daemonsets $n
  echo "----------------------------"
done;
```

Comment: On aws using kops everything this automatically

Answer (score 1):

1). Inside the node pool(lets call it ***old_node_pool*** ) that you want to delete, First Cordon all the nodes one after the other.

```
 kubectl cordon <name_of_node_1>
 kubectl cordon <name_of_node_2>
           ........
```

2). Drain all the nodes of the ***old_node_pool***.

```
 kubectl drain <name_of_node_1>
 kubectl drain <name_of_node_2>
           ........
```

3). Wait to see all the pods are up and running on the new node pool.

4). Delete the old node pool.